# How do I save a screenshot in Tails?

Tags: tails

When I hit "PrtScn" the screen blinks hinting a screenshot is being taken, but then I can't paste it into Gimp. It says there is nothing to paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tails saves print screen images in /home/amnesia (your home directory)

To find the images go to: Applications > Accessories > Files and look for the screenshot file ending .png

Or in gimp you open it through File > Open and it should be there.

https://tails.boum.org/blueprint/doc/screenshots/ Also, this link backs up what I said and explains a whole lot more.